# Does splice exist for TypedArrays or is there an equivalent?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typed-arrays

Is there or is there ever going to be an equivalent of `Array.prototype.splice` for TypedArrays?

I want to be able to delete a range of items from a TypedArray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So TypedArrays in ES6 are not classical Javascript arrays, but closer to an API for a underlying binary buffer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Since `splice` mutates the actual length of array it isn't usable with TypedArrays (http://www.es6fiddle.net/idt0ugqo/).

You can create similar behavior by creating your own splice (although it will be slower).

This is a simple equivalent except that it doesn't account for all nuances of `splice. As @bergi commented, I don't allow negative values.

```
function splice(arr, starting, deleteCount, elements) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    return arr;
  }
  starting = Math.max(starting, 0);
  deleteCount = Math.max(deleteCount, 0);
  elements = elements || [];


  const newSize = arr.length - deleteCount + elements.length;
  const splicedArray = new arr.constructor(newSize);

  splicedArray.set(arr.subarray(0, starting));
  splicedArray.set(elements, starting);
  splicedArray.set(arr.subarray(starting + deleteCount), starting + elements.length);
  return splicedArray;
};

splice(new Uint8Array([1,2,3]), 0, 1); // returns Uint8Array([1,3])
```

http://www.es6fiddle.net/idt3epy2/

Comment: What do you mean by "*retain the empty spaces*"?

Comment: Btw, if you want to more closely emulate [`Array::splice`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.splice), you should care for negative indices (counted from the end) and use `elements = slice.call(arguments, 3)`

Comment: Um, no, you can't. You can insert `undefined`/`null` values by passing them as arguments, but you cannot insert holes - you'd need `delete` for that. Your example yields `[1, null, 3]`, maybe your console is faulty.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there or is there ever going to be an equivalent of `Array.prototype.splice` for `TypedArrays`?

No, because `TypedArrays` cannot change their size. There's no `push`/`pop`/`shift`/`unshift` methods either.

If you want to delete elements from your array, you typically set them to null, and care for those nulls when traversing the array. This also avoids having to shift around all elements after the ones being deleted.

If you really need this, your best bet is to create a new array and copy elements over it (the ones before the deleted section, the new ones, and then the ones after the deleted section). @cdbitesky has given a nice implementation for this.